# What EXACTLY are Instance Variables? Why are they so important?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, instance-variables

I've been reading quite a couple of Objective C books, seeing loads of online video tutorials but am stuck on this one point. I know Instance Variables are coded between braces in an interface, but why are they so special and different from other variables outside the braces, or even the interface.

Ex.

```
@interface CustomClassName : NSObject {
  NSString *myString;
}
@end
```

Why not:

```
@interface CustomClassName : NSObject {}
NSString *myString;
@end
```

Or:

```
@interface CustomClassName : NSObject {}
@end
NSString *myString
```

What is so special about them? Some tell me its the syntax of the language. How do I know whether some variable needs to be declared inside the braces or not. I tried googling this, reading the chapters in my book, (I've got the **Head First iPhone and iPad Development**
 & **Objective C for Absolute Beginners**) but in vain. It would be great if some one could explain the difference!

Comment: They are member of that class. Outside the braces you put the methods of the class and the IBOutlets.

Comment: You should read on basics of OOP.

Comment: I am reading but I'm encountering a problem in understanding the concept. I thought this would be the right place to ask. I'm only 12 so don't be harsh on me not understanding it.

Comment: No need to down vote.   Perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems like youre very new to the world of Objective-C. You should consult existing materials on the subject. It will begin to explain something called `@property`'s and you will begin to understand the purpose of instance variables.

As for me, I use ivars when I want to use primitive types in my class implementation who's value has to persist through the lifetime of the object. So something like:

```
@interface Person : NSObject {
   int age;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I will read about @properties a bit more (There was a chapter on this). Once again thanks for your answer :)